# OAuth2.0 migration for SpringBoot 2.4.1

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

Currently I am migrating our exiting OAUTH Spring Boot Application from 2.2.x to 2.4.x.
Below 2 dependencies got removed in ext.springCloudVersion = "2020.0.0"

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
```

In Spring Cloud 2020.0.0 [Release Notes](https://spring.io/blog/2020/12/22/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-aka-ilford-is-available), it is just mentioned as one line statement as below,

**Spring Cloud Security -
This project was removed and code was moved to the individual Spring Cloud projects.**

Can any one let me know how to find the appropriate project and its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide). If you are implementing APIs these are the 2 main libraries now:

- spring-security-configuration
- spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server

See [this class of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/host/startup/HttpServerConfiguration.java) and the [POM file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/pom.xml) an example.